# How to remove all characters except Alphabets and space in php

Tags: php, regex, string, special-characters

I want to remove everything except Alphabets and spaces in php string.

```
$status = "1 (Delivered to customer)";

$status = preg_replace('/\PL/u', '', $status);

//output
echo $status;
```

The output is: Deliveredtocustomer

I want output: Delivered to customer

How to fix this?

Regards

Comment: Try: `/[^ \pL]/gu` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I use this and it worked.

```
$status = preg_replace("/[^ \w]+/", "", $status);
$status = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $status);
$status = trim($status);
```

Output = Delivered to customer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in just one go. Anything that is not an alphabet or space(performing a case insensitive search), just replace them with an  empty string.

```
<?php

$status = "1 (Delivered to customer)";

echo preg_replace("/[^a-z\s]+/i","",$status);
```

[Online Demo](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yh3hrs6h)