# How to remove all characters except Alphabets, Numbers and Dashes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, special-characters

I want to remove all characters except Alphabets, Numbers and Dashes. Here is my code

```
$tracking = "(TCS-123412&2)";
$tracking = preg_replace("/[^ \w]+/", "", $tracking);
echo $tracking;
```

The output is = TCS1234122

I want the output should be = TCS-1234122

Please help.

Regards

Comment: Hyphen `-` is not part of `\w` hence you need to add `-` in your regex. Change your regex to `[^ \w-]+`

Comment: Did the requirement change from this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73843925/how-to-remove-all-characters-except-alphabets-and-space-in-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include all characters which you do *not* want to exclude in the negative character class.  Note that `\w` also includes underscore, which you presumably want to retain.

```php
$tracking = "(TCS-123412&2)";
$tracking = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/", "", $tracking);
echo $tracking;  // TCS-1234122
```